# Speech Recognition vs. Voice Commands in Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, cortana

I trying to enable Cortana in my Win8 phone app.
Anyway, from MSDN I saw there is speech recognition namespaces as well as voice commands.
I couldn't understand correctly what are is the different between them.

In addition, i'm running my app using the emulator (and not a real device) and I'm getting the following error "something wend wrong try again in a little bit" when i'm tryng to ask cortana one of my new voice commands.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure you got the network connection for your emulator? If you could post come of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can view this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn630426.aspx). Specially read that 'Voice Command' and 'Speech Recognition' part.

'Voice commands' is supported by the system. That means you can start and do some work or initiate some actions based on your phrase outside from the app-like by saying Cortana to launch an app and do something.Like saying this to Cortana-"Foursquare,what's trending?".You have to register the commands in the VCD files.

On the other hand using 'Speech Recognition' you can build an app which can accomplish task based on user's command or speech. You can extend it much more further like custom grammar support. Speech recognition is implemented in your app and accessed by the users of that application.