# Accessing Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition in a Windows Phine Silverlight 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, cortana

I have an older Windows Phone app that has been migrated along from Windows Phone 7 and is currently targeting Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

I'd like to add Cortana Voice Command integration. I started following the steps in [Quickstart: Voice commands with Cortana (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn630430.aspx) and got to C# that referenced the Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition namespace.

The namespace can't be resolved. There are references in the project to:

- .NET for Windows Phone
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhone\v8.1\
- Windows Phone
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Silverlight Kits\8.1\Windows Metadata\

I can use Windows.Phone.Speech.VoiceCommands, but I suspect it won't give the required Cortana integration. The question [Speech Recognition vs. Voice Commands in Windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950394/speech-recognition-vs-voice-commands-in-windows-phone) seems to confirm this.

Creating a new Windows Phone 8.1 app from scratch gives a different set of references:

- .NET for Windows Store apps
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\
- Windows Phone 8.1
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Phone Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\

**How can I access the Cortana API's from a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight App?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone Silverlight apps use the [Windows.Phone.Speech.VoiceCommands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.speech.voicecommands(v=vs.105).aspx) and [Windows.Phone.Speech.Recognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.speech.recognition(v=vs.105).aspx) namespaces.

Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition is the version of this for Windows Runtime apps. See the version section in the [Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx) documentation.

For voice commands in a Windows Phone Silverlight app see the [Voice commands for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx) documentation (and more generally [Speech for Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj206958(v=vs.105).aspx)). This will still integrate with Cortana for voice commands. Speech recognition occurs within the app.

Comment: Great, it was the integration with the Cortana voice commands I wasn't sure about.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify the Question [Speech Recognition vs. Voice Commands in Windows phone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25950394/54026)